# Corona SDK piano app - swapping sounds, etc

Tags: function, audio, lua, coronasdk, piano

So basically I am making piano app in Corona SDK (my first project) and Im new to it. I've asked some questions about my problem on Corona forums but I don't  have achieved exact answers that would help me, so I'm asking for your help. As I said im new, so it may be hard for me to crack out the needed code, but I know that you, more experienced Corona users, can easily do this.

I use this code for each key: (I know that media.playEventSound is pretty weak option to do that, I've seen some libraries about playing audio on Coronalabs like audio.loadSound etc. but if it is possible, of course, I'd like to stay with "media..."-based functions)

```
local widget = require("widget")
local C      = media.newEventSound("C.mp3")

local button_C_Press = function(event)
  media.playEventSound(C, button_C_Press)
end

local button_C = widget.newButton
{
  defaultFile = "NewKey.png",
  overFile    = "NewKey2.png",
  onPress     = button_C_Press,
}
button_C.x = 20; button_C.y = 295
```

I want the piano to have 2 pedals that just switch its sound when they're pressed (I have in my project folder in total 3 different sound arragments - default and 2 pedal sustained audio files) and button that requires note letters on keys.
And here's my problem - how to get this all into one code?
I mean can you write me down there a code for one key like this sample I've posted below but including those features which I just mentioned please? I'd really love to have that solved..
Btw. I know soundTable/fileTable method, however it is called, but I think I have enough time to do each key individually - or use table method maybe - I only wish it was easy, beacuse it is my first project therefore should it be.

Sorry for my English and thanks!

Comment: The second argument to the playEventSound looks wrong. The only required argument to the playEventSound is soundId which you have already provided. [PlayEventSound API Documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/media/playEventSound.html)

Comment: What does 'switch its sound' means?  Can you elaborate more on that? Do you meant that the sound produced by the key alternate between two sounds?

Comment: 'switch its sound' means that if you press the pedal all keys start to operate different audio. Out there are 88 keys. 88x3=264 so 264 audio files in total are needed. For example: C1.mp3-default type, C1sustained.mp3-first pedal type and C1sustained2.mp3-second pedal type. When you press the first pedal the key that plays C based sounds will  immediately swap from C1.mp3 to C1sustained.mp3. Same work with all other keys. And when you press note button, key graphic file changes to one with note inscription.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for more code; I've got this recommended on Corona forums

Boolean variable:

```
local isPedalActive = false
```

And when they have touched the pedal button, then set it to true:

```
isPedalActive = true
```

And then add this to button_C_press function:

```
if event.phase == "began" then
  if isPedalActive = true then
    media.playEventSound(cPedal) --assuming you already loaded your audio above
  end
end
```

Of course, if you have a large number of piano keys, it's better to don't do this individually for each function, rather:

1. Set a specific id for each key, in the widget.newButton table.
2. In the if statement, load the sound there but instead you would retrieve the button's id and play that mp3 file.

(that supports only one pedal)

> ```
>  --create table of key button ids and mp3 files for their pedal noises
> local keys = {
>   {buttonId = "C", pedalNoise = "Cpedal.mp3"},
>   {buttonId = "D", pedalNoise = "Dpedal.mp3"}
> }
>
> function pianoKeys(event)
>   for i = 1, #keys do -- for each table in the keys table, load the sound for each key
>     local keySound = media.newEventSound(keys[i].buttonId .. ".mp3") -- normal sound loaded
>     local keypedalSound = media.newEventSound(keys[i].pedalNoise) --pedal sound loaded
>     function buttonPress(event)  --When they press the key, detect if the pedal is active
>       if event.phase == "began" then
>         if isPedalActive == true then 
>           media.playEventSound(keyPedalSound) --is active, play pedal sound
>         else
>           media.playEventSound(keySound) -- is not active, play regular sound
>         end
>       end
>     end
>     local pianoKey = widget.newButton({
>       id = keys[i].buttonId, -- place appropriate id
>       defaultFile = "new" .. keys[i].buttonId .. "key.png", -- place appropriate defaultFile
>       overFile = "new" .. keys[i].buttonId .. "key2.png", -- place appropriate overFile
>       onPress = buttonPress -- apply above function to each key
>     })
>   end 
> end
> ```

My problem - I dont't want to make sound table. I'd rather to do each key individually. Like that sample of one key's code I've posted below. But how? I dont know how to get everything into one valid thing :/ ( 2 pedals + note button)